# Amending a contract for COVID-19 for reasonable delay for a known event

Tags: contract-law, covid-19, force-majeure

I am negotiating a contract with a client prospect which includes the following Force Majeure clause:

> "Neither party shall be liable for any delay or failure to perform its
>   obligations hereunder resulting from any cause beyond such party’s
>   reasonable control, including but not limited to acts of God, weather,
>   fire, explosions, floods, strikes, work stoppages, slowdowns or other
>   industrial disputes, accidents, riots or civil disturbances, acts of
>   government, inability to obtain any license or consent necessary in
>   respect of any third-party software, delays by suppliers or material
>   shortages, design defects, flaws or errors in third-party equipment or
>   software, epidemics, pandemics, COVID-19 and dangerous conditions that
>   pose a threat to either party’s personnel."

The client has responded with the following statement:

> "The current contract is written in such a way where you could simply
>   collect a check and walk away “because COVID-19” happened. We need
>   this removed and explicitly excluded as it is now preexisting and no
>   longer considered an unknown event. If you would like a separate
>   clause allowing reasonable delay due to COVID-19 caused illnesses that
>   would be fair and reasonable given the ongoing pandemic."

What specific wording can I amend to this contract to fulfill my client prospect's request?

Comment: We can't provide legal advice on this site, and I think offering specific contact language would fall in that category.  See https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/221. You need to talk to your lawyer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What specific wording can I amend to this contract to fulfill my client prospect's request?

Clearly your client's concern is the risk of [your] *unjust enrichment* at his expense. Accordingly, a better approach is to word the clause in terms of (1) *rescinding* the contract if the adverse conditions arise, or (2) *allowing a delay* that is commensurate with the adverse event(s). Your client reflects a preference for the latter approach, although it is unclear whether either of you have pondered the former one.

Side note: Your client's argument of *preexising* vs *unknown* events has no merit, as it oddly purports to require in a contract a degree of uncertainty. Contracts are premised, *inter alia*, on the parties' *awareness* of conditions and circumstances or context in which those contracts are entered. If anything, the fact that COVID-19 is no longer an unknown event enhances the parties' ability to weigh the rights, and duties (with their associated risks) to which they are committing in a contract.